# ASP.NET C# why cant I change the text in a textbox in a webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET project with a simple webpage.When I load the page the textbox display "Hello". When I click the "btnUpload" the text goes away.
I tried !IsPostBack in the Load_Form function gut the just make the text stay the same.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    TextBox1.Text = "Hello";               
}

protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox1.Text = "Good Bye";

}
```

Comment: Could you please post your <@Page .../> attribute? Does it have the AutoEventWireup set to true? Also the HTML for the btnUpload button would be nice to see. It should have the OnClick="btnUpload_Click" attribute set.

Comment: Its working fine for me. On button click Text is changing to Good By. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: Are you missing OnClick="btnUpload_Click" on button click in aspx.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not used

```
if(!IsPostBack) { }
```

inside `Page_load()` method

so modify your code as:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    if(!IsPostBack) {
    TextBox1.Text = "Hello";               
    }
}

protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox1.Text = "Good Bye";
}
```

Because, you have not used this, thats why, on the postback of button it changes the value to `TextBox1.Text = "Good Bye";` but it follows completing the postback with `Page_Load()` so it changes it again to  `TextBox1.Text = "Hello";` that's the reason default value of `Page_Load()` is shown after render.

Comment: Not really. `Page_Load()` comes first, then the event that triggered the PostBack. See http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/page-life-cycle-with-examples-in-Asp-Net/. So the code does work perfectly fine without `if(!IsPostBack)`

Comment: Thank you all for solving this problem for me. Much appreciated.

Comment: If you liked the answer, and if it worked for you please tick it as correct answer, so that, it could help others too. @Ren-Heok

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following condition in the `Page_Load` event handler, not in the `Load_Form`:

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
    TextBox1.Text = "Hello";
}
```

Your button click event handler is ok.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code :

Default.aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="text1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click" />
```

Make sure aspx page contain same code for button as shown above.